# What Actually this line of code `ptr=(char *)&a;` does?

Tags: c

I have the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
   int i;
   float a=5.2;
   char *ptr;
   ptr=(char *)&a;
   for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
      printf("%d ",*ptr++);
}
```

I got the output as `102 102 -90 64`. I couldn't predict how it came, I get confused with this line `ptr=(char *)&a;`. Can anyone explain me what it does? And as like other variables the code `*ptr++` increments? Or there is any other rule for pointers with this case.

I'm a novice in C, so explain the answer in simple terms. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called a [cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion). In C, a cast lets you convert or reinterpret a value from one type to another. When you take the address of the `float`, you get a `float*`; casting that to a `char*` gives you a pointer referring to the same location in memory, but pretending that what lives there is `char` data rather than `float` data.

`sizeof(float)` is `4`, so printing four bytes starting from that location gives you the bytes that make up the float, according to [IEEE-754 single-precision format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format). Some of the bytes have their high bits set, so when interpreted as `signed char` and then converted to `int` for display, they appear as negative values on account of their [two's-complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

The expression `*ptr++` is equivalent to `*(ptr++)`, which first increments `ptr` then dereferences its previous value; you can think of it as simultaneously dereferencing and advancing `ptr`.

Comment: for newbies like me) `sizeof(char)` is `1`. And as this answer said, sizeof(float) is 4. so iterate 4 times in the for loop.

Answer (score 6):

That line casts the address of `a`, denoted `&a`, to a `char*`, i.e. a pointer to characters/bytes. The `printf` loop then prints the values of the four constituent bytes of `a` in decimal.

(Btw., it would have been neater if the loop had been

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++)
    printf("%d ", ptr[i]);
```

)

Answer (score 3):

The line `ptr=(char *)&a;` casts the address of the `float` variable to a pointer of type `char`. Thus you are now interpreting the 4 bytes of which the float consists of as single bytes, which values you print with your `for` loop.

The statement `*ptr++` post-increments the pointer after reading its value, which means, you read the value pointed to (the single bytes of the float) and then advance the pointer by the offset of one byte.

Answer (score 1):

`&a` gets the address of `a`, that is, it yields a pointer of type `float *`. This pointer of type `float *` is then cast to a pointer of type `char *`.

Because `sizeof(char) == 1`, `a` can now be seen through `ptr` as a sequence of bytes.

This is useful when you want to abstract away the type of a variable and treat it as a finite sequence of bytes, especially applicable in serialisation and hashing.